# How to return the maximum element of a slice of a list

Tags: python, max, slice

I am trying to simplify this function at his maximum, how can I do?

```
def eleMax(items, start=0, end=None):
    if end is None:
        end = len(items)
    return max(items[start:end])
```

I thought of

```
def eleMax(items, start=0, end=-1):
    return max(items[start:end])
```

But the last element is deleted from the list.

Comment: That's a really, really weird approach to `max(items)`.  And if you need to slice `max(items[start:end])` or even `max(items[start:])` works.

Comment: Yes you are right, but it is just to exercice :)

Comment: If it's homework, please mark the question with [Homework]

Comment: It is not Homework it is entertainment :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just remove these two lines:

```
if end is None:
    end = len(items)
```

The function will work exactly the same:

```
>>> a=[5,4,3,2,1]
>>> def eleMax(items, start=0, end=None):
...     return max(items[start:end])
...
>>> eleMax(a,2)   # a[2:] == [3,2,1]
3
```

Comment: if i have to calculate that how many times this maximum value occur in given list slice?then how to do this in optimized way if we have longest range of slice

Answer (score 2):

Just use max(items).

Python ranges are 'half-open'. When you slice a list in Python with [start:end] syntax, the start is included and the end is omitted.

Answer (score 2):

```
def eleMax(items, start=None, end=None):
    return max(items[slice(start, end)])
```

Answer (score 1):

When operating over large lists or many calls to this you can avoid the overhead of the slice creating a new list and copying the pointers.

http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice

Itertools contains islice which allows for iterating over the list in place without actually returning a new list for the slice.

```
from itertools import islice

def eleMax(items, start=None, end=None):
    return max(itertools.islice(items, start, end))
```

One current limitation is that negative values are not allowed for start, end, step.